# 500 error while doing Vargrant Up for http shared box

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrant-windows

I'm creating a vagrant base box of windows server 2012, and i want to share it internally for which i'm using Vagrant http share with below command

vagrant share --http 80

```
    C:\Isentia\Vagrant>vagrant share --http 80
==> dev: Detecting network information for machine...
    dev: Local machine address: 169.254.202.14
    dev: Local HTTP port: 80
    dev: Local HTTPS port: disabled
==> dev: Checking authentication and authorization...
==> dev: Creating Vagrant Share session...
    dev: Share will be at: caring-dragon-2751
==> dev: Your Vagrant Share is running! Name: caring-dragon-2751
==> dev: URL: http://caring-dragon-2751.vagrantshare.com
```

and accessing the box with vagrant up in another machine

```
    C:\Isentia\DevVM>vagrant init http://caring-dragon-2751.vagrantshare.com:80
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

C:\Isentia\DevVM>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'http://caring-dragon-2751.vagrantshare.com:80' could not be fo
und. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'http://caring-dragon-2751.vagrantshare.com:80' (v0) for
 provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: http://caring-dragon-2751.vagrantshare.com:80
    default: Progress: 0% (Rate: 0curl:/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

below is the vagrant file content

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config| 
  config.vm.box = "BuzzNumberDevBox"
  config.vm.guest = :windows
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
  config.vm.graceful_halt_timeout = 600
  # Admin user name and password
  config.winrm.username = "vagrant"
  config.winrm.password = "vagrant"  
  config.vm.define "dev" do |dev|
    dev.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.10"
    dev.vm.host_name = "vagranttests.dev"
    dev.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5985, host: 5985, id: "winrm", auto_correct: true
  end
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      # Customize the name of VM in VirtualBox manager UI:
      vb.name = "BuzzNumber-Dev-VM-Web"
  end
end
```

what i do not understand is what could be stopping it from being accessible from any machine. The documentation asked to use the link directly.

Comment: I am also experiencing this error on Ubuntu 15.10 running the ubuntu/trusty64 box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant share is designed for sharing access to an application hosted on a VM, NOT for sharing the actual VM. If you want to share the VM itself you need to run vagrant package to pack it, and then put it on a web server with a metadata.json or at a URL where the other user can add it directly. Can you clarify if you want to copy this box to another machine or simply access a service running on the initial vagrant box?